# Error : cannot find module './commands/0'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was am making a a discord bot and I'm getting the following error, its showing the following error.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './commands/0'
Require stack:
- /home/karthik/VisualStudioCode/Projects/discord-bot/src/bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/karthik/VisualStudioCode/Projects/discord-bot/src/bot.js:12:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/karthik/VisualStudioCode/Projects/discord-bot/src/bot.js' ]
}
```

file structure : [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sppj2.png)

thanks

Comment: Whats inside your commands folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with `Array.map`

```js
commandFiles.map(file => () {
   const commands = require(`./commands/${file}`)
   bot.commands.set(commands.name, commands)
})
```

Be sure that your files exists!